# obj c, xcode making a view transition

Tags: ios

I am trying to make a button on a navigation controller that causes a transition to another view controller (that has a back button to the previous nav view). 
I'm trying to do this programmatically. 
I made a UINavigationController and a UITabBarController. The nav controller is the opening tab of the tab controller. 
I made a subclass of the UIViewController called SubVieController. I haven't added anything to the Sub classes, only the auto generated material.
I've made all my edits to the didFInishLaunchingWithOptions method in Appdelegate.m.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UITabBarController * tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
SubViewController * firstTab= [[SubViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstTab];
SecondViewController *secondTab = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController"    bundle:nil];

SubTableController *table = [[SubTableController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SubTableController" bundle:nil];
navigationController1.tabBarItem.title = @"First Nav";
secondTab.tabBarItem.title =@"Second";
table.title = @"Third Table";
tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navigationController1,secondTab, table];
[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

And I try to move a Button onto the SubViewController.xib file to connect it into the code so I can make a button action. But when I ctrl+drag, nothing inserts into the code like usual.

What do I do to have the button cause a transition from the starting view to a separate view that is still considered to be on the 1st tab, with a back button to the first view which is also in the first tab?

EDIT:
This code seems to work for the button action:
- (IBAction)transition:(UIButton *)sender{
    SubViewController * view2 = [[SubViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have correctly done, the `UITabBarController` should not push a `UIViewController` but a `UINavigationController`. That `UINavigationController` should have a `rootViewController`.

> Not being able to Control-Drag in Interface Builder generally means that the Custom Class in the Identity Inspector is not set properly.

## Connecting IBAction

1. In Xcode project, Select SubViewController.xib
2. Select your button
3. Xcode > View > Utilities > Show Connections Inspector
4. Xcode > View > Assistant Editor > Show Assistant Editor
5. Ensure that *Automatic > SubViewController.m > No Selection* is present. If not, you may not have the Custom Class set properly in IB
6. In Connections, click **Touch Up Inside** grommet and drag onto Assistant, right below `@implementation SubViewController`
7. Enter name, such as **buttonTappedAction**
8. Add code to push the `UIViewController` as needed:

---

**Obj-C**

```
UIViewController * vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"id" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

**Swift**

```
let vc = UIViewController(nibName: "id", bundle: nil)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

---

## Storyboard

> Architecture suggestion:
> Start over using Storyboard

There is no need to write **a single line of code** to implement the above solution using a Storyboard!

[image]

Comment: I got the button action to pop up now, thanks!
But what code do I use to push the new view for the transition? That was the meat of my question.

Comment: Great! Please edit/cleanup your question a bit, then remove comments. Thx.